# c# How get value prom pointer

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

This is my code :

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\UF01\UF01.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_UA01_Entrees", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe internal static extern Boolean UF01_UA01_Entrees(byte Device, byte Module, out ushort* TableData_12bit);

ushort* arr = stackalloc ushort[8];

if (UF01_UA01_Entrees(1, 1, out arr))
{
}
```

My code work great but how can I get the values stored in the pointer ?

I wrote a test programm in C++ :

```
void UA01(byte nb_device, byte module){
    WORD TableData_12bit[8];
    if(UF01_UA01_Entrees(nb_device, module, TableData_12bit)){
        for(int chan=0; chan<MAX_ANALOG_CHANNEL_IN; chan++){
            printf("M%1d%1d:0x%3x ", module, chan+1, TableData_12bit[chan]);                    
        }
    }else{
        printf("\nEchec de lecture");
    }
}
```

This test works but in c# I'm not able to get values from the pointer.
Can you please help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: The TableData_12bit is on the stack and gets disposed when the c++ returns.  So you must allocate the memory for TableData_12bit in c# before the call and then pass the pointer from c# to c++.

Comment: I would also add that if you are asking about how to dereference pointers and suchlike, you'd be FAR better off avoiding this sort of interop approach if at all possible.  There's a good reason why you are forced to use `unsafe` to do this stuff in c#.  This is a last resort for interopability between systems for which you cannot change the source code.  If you CAN change the source code there are other options that won't give you the horrible problems (and you WILL have horrible problems with this approach...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have only a part from source so I cannot change the source code from the DLL. I only need to receive the data from that function. I tried to allocate the memory before the call but I get errors...